# Linq create a list of some type from a list of another type

Tags: c#, linq

suppose i have an

```
List<SomeObject>
List<AnotherObject>
```

and an extention method that returns `SomeObject` Instance when i send it `AnotherObject`

i need to produce a `IList<SomeObject>` from an `IList<AnotherObject>` so without linq i wolud do it as

```
private List<SomeObject> ToListOfProductEntry(List<AnotherObject> list)
        {
            List<SomeObject> result = new List<SomeObject>();
            foreach (var obj in list)
            {
                result.Add(obj.ToSomeObject()); // ToSomeObject() is an extention method
            }
            return result ;
        }
```

how can achive the same result using LINQ, i dont use LINQ alot so i am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) projection to shape data for each element.

```
var result = list.Select(x=>x.ToSomeObject()).ToList();
```

Comment: is there a performance difference between this and the above? for example if i had 20000  elements which one would you use?

Comment: @user1492051 I think if there is some difference, it's very little, not worth mentioning in this case.

Comment: Yeah, this operation will always run in O(n) time.